# Enabling whitespace mode on emacs

Tags: emacs, whitespace

I'm trying to enable whitespace mode but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I've added the whitespace.el file to my .emacs.d/ directory. 
I added the following lines to me .emacs file:

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'whitespace-cleanup)
(add-hook 'before-save-hook (lambda() (delete-trailing-whitespace)))

(require 'whitespace)
```

I did the following in the whitespace.el file:

```
M-x byte-compile-file <path to whitespace.el>
```

I tried executing the following command from any random text in emacs (e.g.: test.c):

```
M-x whitespace-toggle-options RET
```

But I just get a message saying [No match]

What am I missing?

Also, will I have to type in a command to enable the whitespace-mode every time I use emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`whitespace.el` has been included in Emacs for quite a while. Unless you have a very old version, you shouldn't need to manually put it anywhere, or do anything particularly special to use it.

`whitespace-toggle-options` probably isn't the function you want to use. Instead, try `whitespace-mode`:

> Toggle whitespace visualization (Whitespace mode).
>   With a prefix argument *ARG*, enable Whitespace mode if *ARG* is
>   positive, and disable it otherwise.  If called from Lisp, enable
>   the mode if *ARG* is omitted or nil.

If you want to enable it by default, add

```
(global-whitespace-mode)
```

to your init file.